# Measuring Download Speed Java

Tags: java, file, download, measure

I'm working on downloading a file on a software, this is what i got, it sucesfully download, and also i can get progress, but still 1 thing left that I dont know how to do. Measure download speed. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.
This is the current download method code

```
    public void run()
    {
        OutputStream out = null;
        URLConnection conn = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try
        {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(sysDir+"\\"+where));
            conn = url1.openConnection();
            in = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int numRead;
            long numWritten = 0;
            double progress1;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                numWritten += numRead;
                this.speed= (int) (((double)
                buffer.length)/8);
                progress1 = (double) numWritten;
                this.progress=(int) progress1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            echo("Unknown Error: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (in != null)
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null)
                {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                echo("Unknown Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The same way you would measure anything.

`System.nanoTime()` returns a `Long` you can use to measure how long something takes:

```
Long start = System.nanoTime();
// do your read
Long end = System.nanoTime();
```

Now you have the number of nanoseconds it took to read X bytes. Do the math and you have your download rate.

More than likely you're looking for bytes per second. Keep track of the total number of bytes you've read, checking to see if one second has elapsed. Once one second has gone by figure out the rate based on how many bytes you've read in that amount of time. Reset the total, repeat.

Comment: the formula to convert the time that `InputStream.read()` to KB-MB-GB/s? The answers helps to measure the time of execution of `InputStream.read()`.

Answer (score 2):

here is my implementation

```
while (mStatus == DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADING) {
            /*
             * Size buffer according to how much of the file is left to
             * download.
             */
            byte buffer[];
            // handled resume case.
            if ((mSize < mDownloaded ? mSize : mSize - mDownloaded <= 0 ? mSize : mSize - mDownloaded) > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            } else {
                buffer = new byte[(int) (mSize - mDownloaded)];
            }

            // Read from server into buffer.
            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
                break;// EOF, break while loop

            // Write buffer to file.
            file.write(buffer, 0, read);
            mDownloaded += read;
            double speedInKBps = 0.0D;
            try {
                long timeInSecs = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000; //converting millis to seconds as 1000m in 1 second
                speedInKBps = (mDownloaded / timeInSecs) / 1024D;
            } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {

            }
            this.mListener.publishProgress(this.getProgress(), this.getTotalSize(), speedInKBps);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a general idea. Start a timer at the beginning of the download. Now, multiply the `(percentage downloaded)` by the `download size`, and divide it by the `time elapsed.` That gives you average download time. Hope I get you on the right track!

You can use `System.nanoTime();` as suggested by Brian.

Put `long startTime = System.nanoTime();` outside your while loop. and

`long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;` will give you the elapsed time within your loop.

Comment: I dont know how to add it, i have a timer for get progress, but on the GUI

Comment: Put long **startTime = System.nanoTime();** outside your while loop. and long **estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;** will give you the current time

Comment: Yes tried like this `long startTime = System.nanoTime();`, outside while, and `Long end = System.currentTimeMillis()*1000;`, inside, after buffer write, but seems to work only once?, also added this                 `speed= (int) ((1024/(double) (start-end)));`, because the buffer have 1024 bytes

Comment: @JesusDavidGulfoAgudelo, Hey I am looking for the same. Have your code worked after doing as you specified above comment.